# Something went wrong at session launching

Tags: crash, session

I can not launch my Ubuntu session after login.

I tried to update, upgrade, clean, -f install, autoremove, autoclean, nothing have worked.

I see none error, I have no idea how to fix this issue...

[Something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NItg1.png)

I really need help...
Thanks !

Comment: Yes, here I tried all classics commands

Comment: Did you review your /var/log/syslog? The error messages may be quite revealing